# Creating a CSV file using PL/SQL within Shell Script

Tags: shell, csv, plsql, oracle10g

I am trying to create a CSV file within a shell script[test.ksh] and the code snippet is something like below:

```
#Output file path
Group1=/tmp/G1.csv
Group2=/tmp/G2.csv
Group3=/tmp/G3.csv

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $UNAME << EOF 
  WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
  SET FEEDBACK OFF
  SET ECHO OFF
  SET VERIFY OFF
  SET HEADING OFF
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
  SET TRIMSPOOL ON
  SET PAGESIZE 0
  SET NEWPAGE NONE
  set linesize 10000
  set pagesize 1000
  set colsep ","
  set trimspool on
  SPOOL $Group1

select...
from...
where...

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

The same logic is followed for the other two files as well. But when the script is run, I get the following message:

```
./test.ksh
/tmp/G2.csv: No such file or directory
/tmp/G3.csv: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, is there a way to have results from the three different queries go to separate sheets within the same workbook?

The oracle version being used is 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 and I am running this on AIX 5

Comment: "Is there a way to have results from the three different queries go to separate sheets within the same workbook?"  No.  CSV has no concept of multiple sheets within a workbook.

Comment: Where and how $Group2 and $Group3 are used in the script?